# Ubuntu in Virtualbox - WEBrick web server very slow when using local IP address

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, rails

I'm using Ubuntu (Lucid Lynx) to learn Ruby On Rails.  I'm running Ubuntu in VirtualBox (the host is Windows 7 Ultimate), using bridged networking.

When I run my Rails app and point the browser at it using localhost:3000, the app responds immediately and my page is rendered in a second or two.

However, if I use 10.0.0.5:3000 (where 10.0.0.5 is my IP address reported using `ifconfig`), the response from my rails app is *incredibly* slow - maybe 30 seconds or more for the server to respond and render the page.

This happens in both Firefox and Chrome.  Also, when I hit the Rails app from the host (to test it in IE), I get the same slooooooow response.

Any ideas what might be going on?  I've tried it with two different routers, and on two different networks (work and home) with the same result.

Cheers all.

Comment: Are other connections to the virtual Ubuntu box also very slow?  How about connecting the other way, from the Ubuntu VM to the Windows host?

Comment: I can ping the Ubuntu guest from the Windows host, and the ping replies are immediate.

Also, connections from the Ubuntu guest to the Windows host (eg to an IIS website on Windows) are fast.

The only slowness is when I hit the Ubuntu Rails server using the IP address.  Using `localhost` is fine.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but no matter if I use 'localhost' or the numeric IP, the responses is terrible slow. It takes a couple of seconds to load each resource (an image, a js, whatever). I've tried mongrel, thin, unicorn... I guess the only solution is to use passenger under apache right?

Comment: could be related to reverse dns lookups.

Comment: This article might provide an answer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156759/webrick-is-very-slow-to-respond-how-to-speed-it-up

Comment: Just thought I'd mention some important SEO, I came across this post using search term "slooooooow"

Answer (score 8):

Try running

`sudo service avahi-daemon stop`

Also try setting WEBrick /usr/lib/ruby//webrick/config.rb

`:DoNotReverseLookup => true`

Also see: ["Stackoverflow WEBrick slow from remote desktop"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1156759/webrick-very-slow-when-accessing-applications-from-remote-desktop)

Comment: +1 stopping Avahi had an immediate impact. Could you provide an explanation as to why?

Comment: @Amro, not sure. [http://mercenary-code.blogspot.co.uk](http://mercenary-code.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/rails-235-slow-webrick.html) suggested it and mentions deleting the symlink from /etc/rc3.d so it doesn't restart. [This Lighthouse ticket](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/2987-new-233-app-perf-very-poor-from-remote-machine) mentions avahi trying to resolve the reversemapping of 127.0.0.255 causing a timeout. [http://qzdrproject.wordpress.com](http://qzdrproject.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/troubleshooting-networking/) did the digging in strace/wireshark to find the solution.

Comment: This worked for me, it does seem to be caused by a reverse lookup which eventually times out.

Answer (score 1):

**It is WEBrick issue, no problems when you use other web servers.**

I tried Mongrel and Thin with Ruby on Rails 3.0.x, both working great.

I suggest using Mongrel - simply add it to your Gemfile:

```
gem "mongrel"
```

or you can set it only for development and test, not to break production:

```
group :test, :development do
  gem "mongrel"
end
```

Now start server same way as you did before and Mongrel starts instead of WEBrick.

If you prefer Thin, you need to start server with `thin start` or WEBrick will be started.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem occur under both VirtualBox and VMware. Not sure what the problem is... it acts like the Rails server is looking something up that has to be timed out? Rails server reports fast render times in log, but takes forever to respond to each request. Happens in both Rails 2.3.8 and Rails 3.0.3 for me on one particular Ubuntu instance (tried under both VirtualBox and VMware). I've had another Ubuntu VM on another box that didn't have the problem...

After frustratingly chasing this for some time, my solution is to use Phusion Passenger in development mode and Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: this is a non-answer (other than the suggestion just to use Passenger), but I'm documenting my own experience as well as some experiments that I did that hopefully help us come closer to a conclusion.

I have the exact same issue. It came up suddenly. I also have a similar observation to you on the ping front. My Ubuntu guest also runs a regular LAMP stack, and there are absolutely no service issues there. For what it's worth, it seems like `unix_stream_data_wait` is (mostly?) to blame for the hangup. I can't really parse what this means beyond the trivial or how to investigate further.

This seems to be independent of port number (moving rails to a lower port as in `rails s -p 30` doesn't change the issue, and other services set to listen to port 3000 don't encounter the same service issues).

It also seems to be independent of the application code. I tried it with a bare rails app, and the delay reappeared.

The delay also seems to vary in duration, raising a potential problem with the hypothesis that Rails is timing out predicably.

Requests sent in the same "batch" seem to be fulfilled at the same time. This suggests that there's something in the interface between the Rails process and the network handler, where the interface is just damned slow but clears his plate when the transaction eventually does go through.

Overall, weird weird weird.

I just went with [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/install.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

This one is really strange. I've found out, that if I start rails server from putty responses are much faster, than if I start it from VirtualBox window...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WEBrick, you can try using Thin instead. Add thin to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'thin'
```

and install it by running:

```
bundle
```

Start the server by running:

```
thin start
```